# PHP, Regular Expression, don't allow whitespace in password

Tags: php, regex

I was looking for my problem hours and hours but can't find a solution that works fine, or maybe something it's wrong with my RegEx line. I'm looking for part where user won't be allowed to put whitespace in the password. The password field must require this list of regular expressions:

- A minimum of 1 lower case letter [a-z].
- A minimum of 1 upper case letter [A-Z].
- A minimum of 1 numeric character [0-9].
- Password should not contain any special characters, symbols or spaces.
- Passwords must be at least 8 characters in length. Maximum allowed length is 30 characters.

Right now I have generated RegEx line that include everything, but not the part with the whitespaces. If anyone know what is wrong with this line, please correct me and tell me how to fix the problem. Btw, I tried [\S] but doesn't work, I don't know why.

My RegExp line:

```
^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){1,})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){1,})(?=(?:.*\d){1,})(?!(?:.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>]))(.{8,30})$
```

Here is full demo of valid and non-valid passwords with this RegEx: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pX7jN4/23)

Thanks to all that will answer and help me.

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire.

[Don't limit passwords.](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: Try [`^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>])\S{8,30}$`](https://regex101.com/r/pX7jN4/24). BTW, how did *you* try `[\S]`?

Comment: `Password should not contain any special characters, symbols` why not?

Comment: Disallowing spaces, special caracters and enforcing a maximum lenghts are all good ways to make your users password weaker and easier to crack. Let them use the password they want, how long they want.

Comment: Why not just use `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,30}` instead of `.{8,30}` and avoid the last lookahead at all?

Comment: @chris85 because that was required. I'm doing what they asked to.

Comment: @MartinC. You should tell whoever made the spec it is flawed.

Comment: @chris85 Yeah you are right, I will do that.

Comment: @Marxtai I completely agree with you. Maybe I will change the mind of the client

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! That worked perfectly !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried it before ending of the string like this [/S]$. This is my first time doing regexp so I was confused where to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how you tried using `\S`, but this is exactly what you can leverage and use instead of `.` in the main consuming pattern:

```
\A                 # Start of string
  (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]) # Require at least one uppercase letter 
  (?=[^a-z]*[a-z]) # Require at least one lowercase letter
  (?=\D*\d)        # Require at least one digit
  (?![^!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>]*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>]) # No special chars
 \S{8,30}          # Match 8 to 30 non-whitespace chars
\z                 # Unambiguous end of string.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJ7gU7/1) (the demo regex is a bit different since the test is performed against a multiline string, here is the one you should use.)

Here, I used the principle of contrast inside the lookaheads and removed unnecessary non-capturing groups.

Also, it is safer to use `\z` anchor to match the end of string since `$` can match before the final newline in the string.

Answer (score 1):

As others argued, your specification is very weak.
If you ***insist***, you could come up with the following expression which makes use of opposite pairs:

```
^                 # the beginning
(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])  # at least one lower case
(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])  # at least one upper case
(?=\D*\d)         # at least one digit
[\da-zA-Z]{8,30}  # digits and characters from a-z
$                 # the end
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wR2gX4/1).

---

In `PHP` this would be:

```
<?php
$regex = '~
            ^                 # the beginning
            (?=[^a-z]*[a-z])  # at least one lower case
            (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])  # at least one upper case
            (?=\D*\d)         # at least one digit
            [\da-zA-Z]{8,30}  # digits and characters from a-z
            $                 # the end
         ~x';

$password = "Someveryweakpassword123";
if (preg_match($regex, $password)) {
    echo "Yes, it does";
}
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/yzlXob).
Once again, these passwords are very easy to guess and to make it even easier you could as well store them as plain text (but please leave a link here for others not to register on that site :).

Comment: The point of using a negative lookahead disallowing special  characters is that the main consuming pattern can still allow Unicode letters and other symbols. That is why I suggest leaving that as is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! And you are right, same as other answers. I know this make the password to look very week, so I will try to change that and I will remove expression with special characters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Right you are, I'd even go further and would suggest changing the specification all together :)